# c# Calling back from a DLL a code in the winform

Tags: c#, dll, callback

I am building many winform applications where i will be using alot of vertical menus (and since there is no control already existing, i had to build them dynamicly using code based on RadioButtons), so i thought about building a separated DLL that will take care of the creation of those menus, and use this DLL everytime i need that kind of menus, this is a peace of the code that was used to create dynamicly the menu :

```
//Creating a menubutton for each item :
foreach (MenuItem menuItem in _allItems)
{
var menuButton = CreateMenuBottons(menuItem);
_allMenuButtons.Add(menuButton);
}

// Dynamicly create the RadioButton and turn it into a menuButton

private RadioButton CreateMenuBottons(MenuItem item)
{
var index = _allItems.IndexOf(item);
var menuButton = new RadioButton();

menuButton.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
menuButton.AutoSize = true;
menuButton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
...
...
...
...
menuButton.Tag = item.Value;
menuButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

menuButton.CheckedChanged += Radio_CheckedChanged; //My problem is here !!!

return menuButton;

}
```

and this is how i detect which button was clicked on the menu :

```
private void Radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var selectedMenuButton = (RadioButton)sender;
if (selectedMenuButton.Checked)
{
// code that will be excuted when we
// click one menuButton (belongs to the DLL)
// How can i point back to the Exe project
// that is using this DLL !
}
}
```

my problem is that i will be using this DLL in multiple other projects (winforms), and the code that needs to be excecuted in each project will be diffrent from the rest, so how can i call a methode in the winform project from the DLL (without having to change the DLL and recompile each time i use it) ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx old but good

Comment: Just like the radio button allows you to handle it's `CheckedChanged` event, your control needs to provide an event that you app can hook onto. Look up "WinForms create event for user control" for example

Answer (score -1):

**Just a delegate**

You can define a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) specifying the parameters you will give

```
public delegate void MenuButtonClickCallbackDelegate(TypeOfData data);
public MenuButtonClickCallbackDelegate MenuButtonClickCallback;
```

Then call it when you need:

```
private void Radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var selectedMenuButton = (RadioButton)sender;
if (selectedMenuButton.Checked)
{
    if(MenuButtonClickCallback != null)
        MenuButtonClickCallback(parameter);
}
}
```

This is how you assign a function to `MenuButtonClickCallback` from the exe:

```
void MenuButtonClicked(TypeOfData data)
{
}
/*
.
.
.
*/
theObject.MenuButtonClickCallback = MenuButtonClicked;
```

**Event**

Or you can provide an event (if it is possible that more than one method will be called back). You have to define `MenuButtonClickCallback` as follow:

```
public event MenuButtonClickCallbackDelegate MenuButtonClickCallback;
```

And the assignment of a method is done like this:

```
void MenuButtonClicked(TypeOfData data)
{
}
void MenuButtonClickedAnotherMethod(TypeOfData data)
{
}
/*
.
.
.
*/
theObject.MenuButtonClickCallback += MenuButtonClicked;
theObject.MenuButtonClickCallback += MenuButtonClickedAnotherMethod;
```